# What is the most efficient way to display and rename only the keys from a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, nested-json

I have the following JSON structure:

[image]

I will like to display only the yellow highlighted keys, rename them and then put them in a new array.

Renamed is the name of the keys:

act = Actual

prognosis = Prog

Can you please give me an example of how I can implement my plan most efficiently?
plan = Planning

Comment: can u show your attempt, and how would your "Actual" array look like?

Comment: My array should contain the renamed keys. That would be in the case [Actual, Actual, Actual, Actual, Actual, Prog, Planning, Planning, Planning]

Comment: My first approach was to iterate over the JSON with for-loop. Approach would be:

for (let i in ActAndPlanBalance) { const dataInYears = ActAndPlanBalance[i]}

Comment: After iteration I see the individual keys with their data, but I don't know how to display and rename only the keys....

Comment: Won't you lose the reference to "year" if you strip those particular properties out of their containing objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood what you actually want, but if the structure is the same you could do something like

```js
let result: string[] = [];

const nameMap = {
  act: 'Actual',
  plan: 'Planning',
  prognosis: 'Prog'
};

Object.keys(actAndPlanBalance).forEach(x => {
  if (actAndPlanBalance[x]['act']) result.push(nameMap.act);
  else if(actAndPlanBalance[x]['plan']) result.push(nameMap.plan);
  else if(actAndPlanBalance[x]['prognosis']) result.push(nameMap.prognosis);
});
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC7gBcACZYQgQTABMAFaZMAIWQbGFmIF5iBvXYoOIAmAAwBGAOwAuPqXKyA5IVgRCi4gF8ANAKFjxADlm95hJSrUadewQYCcJsxdXqtuoSNFinZc8WVXaw99b3FfBQDLNxtPMWFhJwAHVBAAczAQCABLCBcrd1svYQBmZLZ8mJC7bwAWcsZK4KL4gFYGsCbCzTwCWBJUVQBXaH81VGywNIBtAF1uYjne0EgSMGQAW1gAWWQkhf5BPyUKciHWRRCkioD6RjBJtMu9FPTMnLzb1KfcHvwAeQARgArWDkeAAa1gAE8IOg-FQ6GwWGwOJh4AAzECoACiZAAFugAB7cAB8fD02QxxHh5ERd2YrEYHGmRNm00UfkUs0wxEGEBGhHgSSGEEJ6y2uyS8D8OD0sGgEE4VNplBoDJRzNgrPZimujG5vP5guFovFmx2e2FbDlggVSuIKoR6uRTPY2rZHNeGSyuUNfOGo1NYvQEst0u971ycs0ctwKygcHg0HS6GNo1txCAA).

Comment: I tried your approach... When I call the result array via console.log after the foreach it is always empty. I think that the problem is with ['act'] and so. How do you see this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't correctly do the accessing. 'x' is the key, so you need to grab that object first. Fixed it.